# Python order of conditions

Tags: python, conditional-statements

When I enter this code, the program never throws an error, even if I enter a non-number:

```
user_input = input("Enter a number.")
if user_input.isdigit() and 0 <= float(user_input) <= 10:
    print("A number between 0 and 10.")
else:
    print("Not a number between 0 and 10.")
```

But, if I enter this code, the program throws an error if I enter a non-number:

```
user_input = input("Enter a number.")
if 0 <= float(user_input) <= 10 and user_input.isdigit():
    print("A number between 0 and 10.")
else:
    print("Not a number between 0 and 10.")
```

Does anyone know why? Does it really make a difference in which order I type conditions?

Comment: Clearly, it really does make a difference.

Comment: Maybe reading the error message might help explain why.

Comment: I just tried the first example and it does print an error if I type "a"

Comment: @imreal: Are you sure? It doesn't throw an error for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it matters.

```
if 0 <= float(user_input) <= 10 and user_input.isdigit():
```

First tries to evaluate `float(user_input)`. If `user_input` is a non-number string it would raise a `ValueError`.

```
if user_input.isdigit() and 0 <= float(user_input) <= 10:
```

First tries to evaluate `user_input.isdigit()`. If it returns `False` then `0 <= float(user_input) <= 10` isn't evaluated at all.

This behavior is called "short-circuiting". 
In the predicate `A AND B`, `B` will be evaluated only if `A` is `True`.
Likewise, in the predicate `A OR B`, `B` will be evaluated only if `A` is `False`.

Comment: Interesting. I always thought the computers checked every single condition in any boolean statement. So it is possible to improve a program;s efficiency by simply putting likelier conditions first?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the `isdigit()` method is false, so the next condition is not checked.  In the second case, the `float()` is attempted and raises and exception:

```
... float('bob')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: bob
>>>
```